# python windows application automation(how to check is icons available to click or not)

Tags: python, windows, automation, pywinauto

how to check is icons available to click or not in a application. I tried pywinauto and pyautogui but didn't find any method to check.

ex: In a application I want to check is there a file to save it or not.
if file exist save icon highlighted else not.

[1]: i.stack.imgur.com/MJmjA.png [2]: i.stack.imgur.com/nJRP7.png

Comment: Which icons do you mean? Which kind of application? Picture seems not attached. Please ask detailed question to meet StackOverflow rules.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJmjA.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJRP7.png I want to check is save button clickable or not? it is ellisys application.

Comment: And what? Is it a toolbar? Did you try to run `Inspect.exe` for it and switch it to "UI Automation" mode? `Inspect.exe` is a part of Windows SDK. Please run it and make a screenshot of toolbar button properties. Also it's interesting which code did you try? Please edit question with more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pyautogui` library, as its helps in automation in any sort of interface.

> - Here basically, you take screenshots of the surface which needs to be clicked, in your case, take the screenshot of your checkbox along with the text which you want to clicked or ticked.
> - Then locate the screenshot in windows, when your application is on the top of screen.

You can see in [PyautoGUI Screenshots](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#)

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[pyautogui](/questions/tagged/pyautogui)[automation](/questions/tagged/automation)